# Installing windows C# form application with oracle database support on computers with no oracle installed

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle, oracle10g

I have created a windows C# form application in VS 2012 which makes use of oracle 10g database.I created a setup file of it, and installed it on my PC,it works correctly.But when installed  on another PC with no oracle installed ,It did not work, i mean no data from database was displayed.My question is how to include oracle database tables in the setup file of the application, so that it can be installed on PC with no oracle installed?

Comment: how do you connect to the database?

Comment: you don't :) "tables" cannot be installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, 2 possibilities here:

- either you have your Oracle database installed on your PC ("locally"), and so when running your form application from the same machine it's easy to target it
- or your DB runs on another machine/server, but you have setup your PC to target it. When you have an Oracle client installed on your machine, the **tnsnames.ora** which is normally in the **network/admin** subdir of your Oracle client installation directory [should contain an item that points to this DB instance](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora). If so, you just have to install an Oracle client on the machine where you want to deploy your app, and setup the **tnsnames.ora** the same way.

This is the standard way to distribute an application, anyway: make an application/a DB run in a central place accessible by all in order to target it easily. If you have the DB running locally on your PC, you may think about changing your architecture.